# Getting A Grid of Squares to Slowly Change Size

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

So I've got an animation concept where the background of the website is a large grid of squares. When you load up the website, the squares are small, 5vw x 5vw. Gradually, they smoothly get larger, until they get to 7vw x 7vw, when they start going back down to 5vw.

You'd understand the question a lot better if you just run this:

```js
var x = $(".x");
var table = $("#background");

animation();

function animation() {
  x.animate({
    height: "7vw"
  }, 2000);
  table.animate({
    borderSpacing: "3vw"
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(reverse, 2000)
}

function reverse() {
  x.animate({
    height: "5vw"
  }, 2000);
  table.animate({
    borderSpacing: "5vw"
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(animation, 2000)
}
```

```css
#background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 5vw;
}
.x {
  height: 5vw;
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="background">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="x"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem with this, as you can probably see, is that it doesn't work. I'm not really sure what it's doing at all. I think it's starting with a ridiculous amount of space between the squares and with the squares really small, then bringing them closer and making them larger, and I have no idea why. It's also alternating between making them larger and making them smaller, not making them larger and then smaller. Ideas, anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your table.animate calls.  I'm not 100% sure what they are trying to do (made some assumptions), but it's animating independently of the squares, causing a weird appearance.

If you do it without these calls, the squares grow smoothly, though not sure if it's the appearance you want.  See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0xzvjz04/2/

Changed javascript:

```
var x = $(".x");
var table = $("#background");

animation();

function animation() {
    x.animate({
        height: "7vw",
        width: "7vw"
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(reverse, 2000)
}

function reverse() {
    x.animate({
        height: "5vw",
        width: "5vw"
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(animation, 2000)
}
```

Changed css:

```
#background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 3vw;
}

.x {
    height: 5vw;
    width: 5vw;
    background: #333333;
}
```